# How to calculate Share Price based on Outstanding Shares of $ATVI?

Tags: equities, finance

I am looking at the latest 10-Q SEC Filing of ATVI stock (March 31, 2022). (RefLink: https://investor.activision.com/sec-filings/sec-filing/10-q/0001628280-22-011987)

The Balance Sheet states the following:
[image: ATVI Balance Sheet March 31, 2022]

I would like to know how to calculate the Price Per Share (Book Value). Based on my understanding (I am not a finance guy) this is done by taking the Shareholders Equity and divide the number by the Outstanding shares. How do I get the outstanding shares as of March 31,2022 which is where this Balance Sheet is from ? Websites tell me it should be mentioned in the Common Stock section but as you can see it does not mentioning outstanding shares only, authorized and issued. I also do not understand when I add the issued shares, how can they be large than the authorized amount?

How do I calculate the outstanding shares and the the Price Per Share as of this Balance Sheet ?

Comment: (1) "Issued shares are the total shares issued by the Company. Whereas outstanding shares are the shares with the shareholders, i.e., it does not include the shares repurchased by the Company. Thus, subtracting treasury shares from the issued shares will give outstanding shares."  (2) A note: when you divide Shareholders Equity by Outstanding shares, what you get is called Book Value of Equity per Share (it is potentially confusing to refer to it as Price Per Share as you do. "Price per share" is ambiguous and can refer to market price or to book price)

Comment: Thanks. That makes it clear. However what I still do not get is, why are there two numbers listed for issued shares ? Like it looks to me they issued 1.21B and 1.20B Shares in March. Or are both numbers mean something different ? Like if I sum those up it would be at least 2.4B shares issued ?

Comment: 1,210,312,481 in March 2022 and 1,207,729,623 in March 2021 (i.e. one year before). Looks like a few additional shares were isssued during this period, so the number increased slightly. Do not add these two numbers. If you want you can **average** them to find the average number during this period. Or more simply use the more recent number 1,210,312,481.